# Why I cannot disable 128bit cipher in node https?

Tags: node.js, https

I try to only use 256bit cipher suites only with following setup:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const constants = require('constants');

const serverKey = 'server.key';
const serverCrt = 'server.crt';

httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(serverKey),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(serverCrt),
    secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1,
    ciphers: [
        'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384',
        'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384',
        "HIGH",
        "!aNULL",
        "!eNULL",
        "!EXPORT",
        "!DES",
        "!RC4",
        "!MD5",
        "!PSK",
        "!SRP",
        "!CAMELLIA"
    ].join(':')
};

https.createServer(httpsOptions, (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello world\n');
}).listen(8000);
```

However [sslscan](https://github.com/rbsec/sslscan) and ssllabs.com (my blog is using the same httpsOptions) testing show I still have

- 128bit ciphers
- NON-GCM ciphers

Following is out put from sslscan:

```
[23:13:03]JS@JS-Mac-mini ~> sslscan localhost:8000
Version: 1.11.8
OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017

OpenSSL version does not support SSLv2
SSLv2 ciphers will not be detected

Testing SSL server localhost on port 8000

  TLS Fallback SCSV:
Server supports TLS Fallback SCSV

  TLS renegotiation:
Session renegotiation not supported

  TLS Compression:
Compression disabled

  Heartbleed:
TLS 1.2 not vulnerable to heartbleed
TLS 1.1 not vulnerable to heartbleed
TLS 1.0 not vulnerable to heartbleed

  Supported Server Cipher(s):
Preferred TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384   Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384       Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-GCM-SHA384
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-SHA256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256   Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256       Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-GCM-SHA256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-SHA256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-SHA

  SSL Certificate:
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
RSA Key Strength:    2048

Subject:  localhost
Issuer:   localhost

Not valid before: Jun 13 19:06:29 2016 GMT
Not valid after:  Jun 13 19:06:29 2017 GMT
```

I expect to see only the following ciphers:

```
Preferred TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384   Curve P-256 DHE 256
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're including `HIGH` in your SSL cipher configuration, which includes all the ciphers that OpenSSL considers high strength (128bit or above), and then you're excluding some specific other groups of ciphers. Remove `HIGH` and you'll just get the ciphers you want.

You can see what's in each group in OpenSSL from the command line with `$ openssl ciphers -v HIGH`

Alternatively you might just be able to specify the ciphers you want, and remove everything else.

Answer (score 1):

add !AES128 to disable these 128bit ciphers.
sample:

```
ciphers: "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!SRP:!CAMELLIA:HIGH:!AES128"
```

then supported ciphers will be:

```
  Supported Server Cipher(s):
    Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLS11  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLS11  256 bits  AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
    Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  AES256-SHA256
    Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  AES256-SHA
```